# Running Lua scripts - Windows 64 bit

Tags: windows, lua

Recently I've started learning Lua programming language but I don't know how to run the scripts I'm writing(.lua files). Basically I'm practicing in eclipse with Eclipse LDT, but I want to run my scripts more freely, like in cmd. What do I need to do?

Comment: can't you simply open cmd.exe , cd to the directory containing you script and type lua myscript.lua  ?

Comment: No. Apperantely I don't have the Lua compiler. The problem is I don't know exactly what I need and what I don't need

Comment: hmmm.....I just googled "lua for windows". You might find the first few results interesting / useful.

Comment: Then install the Lua interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Lua source [here](http://www.lua.org/download.html) or the binaries [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaBinaries). After that, simply install the Lua interpreter and open your command line.

There are two ways to use Lua with the shell:

directly:

> lua

running a Lua script:

> lua script.lua

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808361/recommendations-for-a-lua-ide-and-debugger-on-windows) you can find various Lua editors or development environments.

Please use google or other search engines first.